# Apache serve only on domain name and not hostname

Tags: apache, ubuntu-18.04, nextcloud

I am running a nextcloud on a hoster. By default, the server was reachable on `12345.hoster.com`. I also bought a domain `mysite.biz` and set the A record to the IP of my server.
Since it runs Apache2, I changed the the conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName mysite.biz
DocumentRoot /var/www/nextcloud
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/nextcloud>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This conf (and its equivalent for port 443) are the only confs enabled. However, I can still reach my site by opening `12345.hoster.com` in a browser. 
How can I serve my site only via `mysite.biz`?

EDIT --

my `/etc/hosts/` does indeed contain only the "old" hostname:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback

# Auto-generated hostname. Please do not remove this comment.
123.123.123.123 12345.hoster.com 12345
```

As far as I can tell, the DNS entries are okay:

```
dig mysite.biz

; <<>> DiG 9.13.7 <<>> mysite.biz
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 38461
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mysite.biz.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mysite.biz.     150 IN  A   123.123.123.123

;; Query time: 17 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1)
;; WHEN: Sa Mär 09 15:51:29 CET 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56
```

and

```
[...]
;mysite.biz.            IN  CNAME

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
mysite.biz.     3109    IN  SOA somename.dzone.com. hoster.datacenter.com. 2019030802 86400 7200 604800 7200
[...]
```

Comment: This does not look like an Apache problem. You need to check why your 12345 domain is leading you to the site. Might be a DNS. May be you have a CNAME record. Or may be is redirected from the /etc/hosts of your own computer. Please post your DNS records.

Comment: @Juan I updated my question with the content of my `etc/hosts` and the result of the dig command

Comment: What about the line with `# Auto-generated hostname. Please do not remove this comment.
123.123.123.123 12345.hoster.com 12345` ? Is that IP the same IP of your mysite site? And another question: has the hoster.com account any internal redireccion to the other site? May be from a control panel-ish setup

Comment: Yes, that is the IP of my server and the same IP as in the A Record. I have changed that line to `mysite.biz`, but that did not change anything. The only settings on the hosters site I can influence are the DNS records (A, AAA, etc), but they are changed to my domain.

Comment: mmmh... do you have a DNS server installed inside your network? Like a BIND in 192.168.1.1? If so, clean the cache or turn it off. Once you get sure that there is no DNS in the middle, run a `dig 12345.hoster.com` and post the information. Note that it'd be very useful if you post the real information so I can check the status from outside your network. But I do not want to compromise your security.

Comment: I checked my domain via https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/ and it has the right A Record. Form my googling it seems that my hoster also keeps an A Record to my server IP. I cannot even change the hostname on the system (it will be restored after a reboot) and their documentation states, that this is on purpose. So maybe, I configure Aapache to return a 404 on anything, that is not `mysite.biz`